# Error while making fetch request to quiz API

Tags: javascript, curl, fetch-api

I am getting an error while making fetch request the curl command works fine which is:

```
curl https://quizapi.io/api/v1/questions -G \
-d apiKey=my_key
```

but when I do a JavaScript request

```js
fetch("https://quizapi.io/api/v1/questions", {
  body: "apiKey=my_key",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
  },
  method: "POST"
})
   .then((res) => res.json())
   .then((data) => {
      console.log(data);
   });
```

I get an error :

> Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

**Edit**

```
fetch('https://quizapi.io/api/v1/questions', {
        headers: {
          'X-Api-Key': `${apiKey}`,
        },
      })
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((data) => {
          console.log(data);
        });
```

Comment: Is there perhaps more JS code than you're showing? Where do you handle the response? If you're attempting to use `response.json()`, have you confirmed that the API actually responds with JSON and not HTML? Have you checked `response.ok` to make sure the request was successful?

Comment: I updated the code please check it

Comment: If you're running this in the browser, check your dev tools _Network_ panel. The API appears to be responding with HTML instead of JSON. There's probably an error being reported in the response

Comment: Yes the response it ```woops something went wrong``` (I am having problem with the API! not in making request)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting an HTML response (probably a 401 error). According to the [API docs](https://quizapi.io/docs/1.0/authentication), you need to pass the authentication token as the `apiKey` query parameter or `X-Api-Key` header.

The `-G` flag in `curl` makes it a GET request and passes any data parameters (`-d`) into the query string. That's where you're going wrong.

You are making a POST request via `fetch()` and attempting to send the credentials in the request body. That's not going to work.

Try this instead, making a GET request and passing the credentials in the header

```js
fetch("https://quizapi.io/api/v1/questions", {
  headers: {
    "X-Api-Key": apiKey
  },
  // the default method is "GET"
}).then(res => {
  if (!res.ok) {
    throw new Error(res) 
  }
  return res.json()
}).then(console.log).catch(console.error)
```

---

The alternative is to include the `apiKey` in the query string

```js
const params = new URLSearchParams({ apiKey })

fetch(`https://quizapi.io/api/v1/questions?${params}`)
```